# How to distinguish country between the meanings of nation and countryside?

Tags: ambiguity

> Which country do you come from?

What is the meaning? **Which countryside do you come from?** or **Which nation do you come from?**

Comment: *strictly* depends on the country this question is asked in. In *India*, if you ask this, the reply expected is some *other nation* and **never** anything else.  County, countryside are not so popular here. Instead, we use 'rural areas'.

Comment: I agree with Maulik V although that I don't believe that there is any other meaning that comes with that word other than _which nation do you come from_. If so, I haven't heard of it.

Comment: I would understand "which country do you come from?" as "which nation do you come from?". Maybe it's just me, and I'm not really sure about this, but "which countryside do you come from?" sounds unnatural to me.

Comment: No @CipherBot [one meaning of *country*](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=country) is the place **outside cities and towns** as in *"his poetry celebrated the slower pace of life in the country"*. This is the reason, I'm not answering this question! :)

Comment: @MaulikV No, I don't mean that. I meant of the generally assumed meaning in which the questioner may ask of that question. I simply haven't heard anybody use it in any other forms before.

Comment: I think usually it's "the country" for the rural areas within a country. Of course you shouldn't say "which the country do you come from?". Perhaps, "what part of the country do you come from?"

Comment: @MaulikV Am sure you have heard of country liquor. Or country-made revolver. These are terms widely used in India that do use the other meaning of the word "country"; the equivalent of the Hindi 'desi'.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How to distinguish?

**The country**, when it is used to mean *any* sparsely populated rural area far outside the bounds of a city, cannot be used with "which", because the countryside does not consist of discrete bounded areas but is rather a continuous swath of green. There may be small villages dotting the countryside, but **the country** and **the countryside** refer to an anonymous stretch of rurality.

So, if the question contains the word "which", it is almost a certainty that the question is asking about nationality.

**Which country do you come from?

--England.**

**What area of Massachusetts do you come from?

--I'm from the western part of the state, out in the country.

Did you enjoy life in the countryside, or were you eager to get to a big city?**

Answer (score 3):

"Which" is used to ask or talk about the choice between two or more things. It means that the noun which follows it must be countable. " The country" meaning "the countryside " is an uncountable noun."Country " as "nation" is a countable noun. I think it's easy to make a choice.